# USB Debugging in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am having an Android Phone (**Motorola Quench XT3**) running version **2.1**.
I have installed android `SDK` (including the USB driver) in my Windows XP OS.

I enabled `USB` debugging in my phone and connected it to the computer.
The phone is recognized and the SD card gets mounted in my computer.

When I launch the `DDMS` tool from my computer, it is not listing my device.

Am I missing any steps here or the `USB` debugging works only with specific phones.

Comment: It's not really complicated. I think you are not doing something wrong..
what you getting in ./adb devices ?

Comment: Some phones give you a choice upon usb connection - debugging, mount sdcard, charge only.  Could that be set wrong?  Mounting the SD is not a prerequisite to debugging, it's a separate function and only by virtue of being a composite device are both even possible at the same time.

Comment: I restarted the abd server using the above mentioned commands and ./adb devices does not list any devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any of those things.I had the same problem with debugging my HTC thunderbolt. All you have to do is download the official software from the phone's website.

Try one of these two links:
http://www.nero.com/download.php?id=motorolamedialink

http://www.motorola.com/consumers/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=0351f6a559431210VgnVCM1000008406b00aRCRD

Download and install the software, and it should work. it did for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
adb devices
```

should show all the android devices attached to your machine. In case it does not show up, restart the adb server i.e.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

I faced the same problem and the above steps helped. 
YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me with several phones earlier, Motorola Atrix, Sansung Galaxy.
I found out that I needed to install the official driver from the manufacturer even if the device is installed by Windows.

[Motorola Driver download here](http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Support/Experiences/Global_Drivers/MotoHelper_2.0.49_Driver_5.0.0.exe)

Answer (score 1):

Install all drivers, the motorola media link, restart your computer. Then plug your device, and select USB CHARGE ONLY. It may work in other modes, but the documentation says that. Also, try using eclipse with the adb plugin. When it prompts you to select a target device, your phone should appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try usbsnoop or wireshark (in Linux using usbmon) to see the package exchange.

Answer (score 0):

**ADB can't work while your phone is connected as a storage device** (it could in theory, but I've never seen a device acting as multiple targets)

ADB uses, afaik, some sort of networking. Your phone exposes itself as either a storage device, a network (tethering) device or a special device (used for debugging via adb).

This "special" modus requires a per-phone driver. Make sure you got the correct one by motorola. You should reboot after the install.

Try not to choose any "use as XYZ via USB" option, let it time out (or choose charge only), and make sure that there is no default set.