# Nexus one not showing in DDMS problem

Tags: android, ddms

I want to run my application in Nexus one.But when i am connecting NEXUS One through USB, it is not showing  in the list of DDMS.I searched in internet.One solution was there which says to connect it in other port.I did so but it is of no use.So any one wanna help?

Comment: Could you please provide additional information like which operating system you use?

Comment: I am using Window OS and Eclipse for my project with ADT plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying on phones from Windows, you need to have the proper driver installed. For the nexus devices you need this google driver: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this,

[USB Debugging in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227927/usb-debugging-in-android)

As you can see, some devices require Drivers to be installed. So better download an driver from the link provided and I hope it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that "Enable USB debugging" is checked.