# Debug in Nexus one Android Usb Accessory Mode

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb

When we use Nexus one in Usb Accessory Mode , we should turn off the adb mode in the phone. or the Usb Accessory can not access.

Does anybody know if the adb mode turned off , how can we debug the apk ?
I tried Remote debug . failed.

Google sdk said :
 0x2D00 is reserved for Android-powered devices that support accessory mode. 0x2D01 is reserved for devices that support accessory mode as well as the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) protocol, which exposes a second interface with two bulk endpoints for ADB. You can use these endpoints for debugging the accessory application if you are simulating the accessory on a computer. In general, do not use this interface unless your accessory is implementing a passthrough to ADB on the device.

But How can we activate the Nexus one with PID 2D01 ?  My Nexus one only works with 2D00

Add a Reference Here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html#determine

Answer (score 3):

I too am trying to debug an Android Accessory Mode (ADK) device while it is connected to a Nexus S phone.  Although I have not been able to debug my hardware I have found it useful to use a Linux system as the Accessory Mode device.  This allows the use of [usbmon](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt) and [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to observe the underlying protocol.

If anyone has a way to debug Android-to-Accessory communication without buying a USB Protocol Analyzer (**www.openvizsla.org**) please help.

Nexus-Computing GmbH's (**android.serverbox.ch/?p=262**) simplectrl.c (Linux-side) and UsbTest (Android-side) were invaluable and the basis for the following:

What to do under Ubuntu 11.04 to capture USB traffic:

1) Enable usbmon:

`mount -t debugfs none_debugs /sys/kernel/debug`

`sudo modprobe usbmon`

2) Install Wireshark and helper programs:

`sudo apt-get -y install flex bison wireshark libusb-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev`

`apt-get source libusb`

3) Download and install libpcap, (**www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.1.1.tar.gz**)

`tar xvf libpcap-1.1.1.tar.gz`

`cd libpcap-1.1.1`

`./configure`

`make`

`sudo make install`

4) Connect your Android device to your Linux system and make sure it is connected:

`?/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices`

5) Compile and upload the USBTest App onto your Android device using eclipse (**developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html**) or your preferred method.  You need Google APIs 2.3.3 installed.  I have updated simplectrl and UsbTest with some bug fixes to make sure they work out of the box.  They are available on the LUFA Library Support List (**groups.google.com/group/lufa-support/msg/2e6d76c92d9e828a**) as an attachment.

6) Determine the correct USB Bus to capture.  `lsusb` will output something like:

`Bus 001 Device 057: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc.`

The above means that your Android device is on Bus `001`.

7) Start Wireshark with root privileges and select the appropriate capture interface:

`gksudo wireshark`

8) Connect your Linux system to your Android device and run `simplectrl`:

`rm ./simplectrl; gcc simplectrl.c -I/usr/include/ -o simplectrl -lusb-1.0 -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0`

9) Example Wireshark capture session of simplectrl-to-USBTest communication is available as an attachment on the LUFA Library Support List (**groups.google.com/group/lufa-support/msg/8c740dfa58a1d1fd**).

---

If you want to stream usbmon captured data you can do the following:

1) list usbmon interfaces: `sudo ls -laR /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/`

2) use `lsusb` to list connected devices.  Output will be something like:

`Bus 001 Device 057: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc.`

3) The above means that your Android device is on Bus `001` so you should capture data from bus 1:

`sudo sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1u`

*Note Bus 0 captures all buses.  The `u` defines the output format of the data.  For more information read (**www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt**).

Comment: Hi Opendous , can you tell me your Nexus S VID ? I just wanna know it is different or not. I have no luck to get the vid 2D01.

Comment: I installed a aLogCat on the phone , can only get some log, better than nothing.

Comment: I use a Nexus S with 2.3.4 installed and VID=0x18D1, ACCESSORY_PID=0x2D01 in simplectrl.c. I am currently working to compile an updated Android kernel with usbmon built-in.  I will post a tutorial when ready.  Forgot to enable stackoverflow email notifications under prefs so I missed your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging USB Accessory through wifi seems only possible on Nexus devices (I used Nexus 7 and Nexus 7 2013). I tried many others (Samsung's, Motorola), they don't detect accessory when USB debugging is enabled in settings. Also tried hardware usb switcher - does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this kind of information,

[Nexus one not showing in DDMS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895294/nexus-one-not-showing-in-ddms-problem/6895365#6895365)

And also take a look at my answer there.

Comment: Sorry , It was a different Question . The device works fine in adb mode . My question is how to debug in USB ACCESSORY MODE . this mode use a different driver on PC . And seems need to close the ADB on device (I am not sure about this) .