# Nexus one device not showing up in DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, ddms

I have enabled Network debugging in my Google Nexus One device. device is connected to the WiFi network. but device is not show up in eclipse DDMS perspective.

how can i fix this ?

Comment: http://www.jessechen.net/blog/debugging-your-android-app-wirelessly-on-an-android-smartphone/

Comment: Please refer this, it may be useful to you,                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895294/nexus-one-not-showing-in-ddms-problem